# How to fix error of ckfinder error with codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor, ckfinder

How to fix **“The file browser is disabled for security reasons. Please contact your system administrator and check the CKFinder configuration file.”** error after working ckeditor with ckfinder one codeignighter site

Answer (score 0):

you should enable CKFinder:

```
enabled   = "false"
```

Refer this forum for more details: 
http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/file-browser-disabled-for-security-reasons.

Enabling CKFInder is not secured one. You should take some security measurement to protect your site.

Check this [link](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Problems-CKFinder) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
function CheckAuthentication()
{

    return false;
}
```

By default `CheckAuthentication()` it is disabled for security reason, because it would allow anyone to upload files to your server.

For testing purposes you can return `true` but the point is that you implement some logic to only authorize autenticated user.

```
function CheckAuthentication()
{
    //put some logic here

    return isset($_SESSION['IsAuthorized']) && $_SESSION['IsAuthorized'];
}
```